# Aura Component in LWC- Possible?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Would like to know if we can include an AURA component as a child component in LWC component?

Comment: No, you can't  add

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you can not add Aura component inside Lightning web component.

> You can compose Aura components from Lightning web components, but not
> the other way around. To communicate down the hierarchy, parents set
> properties on children. To decide when and how to nest a Lightning web
> component in an Aura component, it’s important to understand facets
> and slots.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.interop_aura_composition)

Answer (score 6):

No - a LWC can't contain an Aura Component:
See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.get_started_lwc_or_aura) for details

> NOTE A Lightning web component can’t contain an Aura component. When
> you develop a Lightning web component, its DOM subtree must be
> composed entirely of Lightning web components.

Answer (score 5):

Aura components can contain Lightning web components. But Lightning web components can’t contain Aura components.

Have a look into the standard documentation about [Aura Coexistance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.interop_aura_composition)